# How to remove the html link at the left bottom PDF printed by Print-To-PDF Headless Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, printing, google-chrome-headless

I'm using the following command to print a html file to PDF by Headlesss Chrome:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless file:"C:\1.html" --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf="E:\Sets1.pdf" --virtual-time-budget=15000`

The output PDF is very good

[image]

I would like to ask if there is any option to remove the link on the left bottom corner while keeping the page number on the right bottom one.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Instead of calling up an entire web-browser, why not use the HTML rendering engine only to do the work? Use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to perform the conversion.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I've tried wkhtmltopdf, but the output PDF is very ugly :(

Comment: Ahhh... Okay... BTW, it's footer you need to remove. I couldn't find any documentation for `--print-to-pdf`. Can you guide me to there, I'll check something for that?

Comment: Guess this? [Getting Started with Headless Chrome  |  Web  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#create_a_pdf)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman you can read it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/592974/how-to-print-to-save-as-pdf-from-a-command-line-with-chrome-or-chromium#comment1543348_737587).

Comment: I got my first comment from that link! 

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I read it before, my problem is that I have no experience with CSS, so I'm looking for a simple solution. For example, an option in cmd command.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman You are very welcome :)) I have a question, just for my curiosity. Why are other softwares or packages unable to math Google Chrome ability in printing PDF?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman The only "official" information I can find is https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF.

Comment: Let me see if I can help you somehow...

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Actually, this is a unnoticeable detail on the good quality output PDF, don't let this problem take you much time :v

Comment: Ha ha, I am actually trying out VM and other stuff, if that works... But no...